# How common is library sharing between containers and host?

Tags: docker, shared-libraries

I am researching shared libraries between containers from security point of view.

In many security resources, the shared library scenario, where containers share dependency reference (i.e. same file) is discussed, I can come up with two scenarios:

1. De-facto discussed scenario - where some lib directory is mounted from the host machine to container
2. Invented scenario - where a shared volume is created for different containers (different services, replicate set of same container, or both), and it is populated with libraries which are shared between all of the containers.

Despite the discussions, I was not able to find this kind of behavior in real world, so the question is: How common is this approach?

A reference to an official and known image which uses this technique would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not considered a best practice at all.  A single Docker image is intended to be self-contained and include all of the application code and libraries it needs to run.  SO questions aside, I’ve never encountered a Docker image that suggests using volumes to inject any sort of code into containers.

(The one exception is the `node` image; there’s a frequent SO question about using an anonymous volume for `node_modules` directories [TL;DR: changes in `package.json` never update the volume] but even then this is trying to *avoid* sharing the library tree with other contexts.)

One helpful technique is to build an intermediate base image that contains some set of libraries, and then building an application on top of that.  At a mechanical level, for a particular version of the `ubuntu:18.04` image, I think all other images based on that use the physically same `libc.so.6`, but from a Docker point of view this is an implementation detail.